# Copy Editor badge not working?

Tags: support, badges

As you can see [here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all), I have more than 500 edits on the site.

However, the [copy editor badge](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/badges/49/copy-editor) has not been assigned.

Am I misunderstanding what I need to do to get the badge or is it a bug?

Comment: The criteria for the user listing and the badge are different, I don't remeber the exact differences though.

Comment: this is covered on the main meta -- edits to your own posts don't count, for example, and only body or title edits on other people's posts count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The progress towards copy editor is now displayed on the review page

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/review

see

[Contradictory information for Copy Editor progress](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119707/contradictory-information-for-copy-editor-progress)